# Spring Boot with Scala

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scala

Consider there is a trait defined (Parent)
and two classes are defined class child1 and class child2 extending Parent (annotated with @Component)
And a third class Factory(Parent: Array[Parent]) (annotated with @Service)

```
trait Parent {}

@Component
class Child1 extends Parent {}


@Component
class Child2 extends Parent {}

@Service
class Factory(children: Array[Parent]) {
  
   @PostConstruct
   val test: Unit = children.map(x => println(x.getClass)
   // printing Child1 and Child2
}

I am autowiring the Factory class in the Class Field like this  
class Main @Autowired()(factory: Factory) {
 //
}
```

I am very new to Scala.
How the children is getting initilaized with both the child classes even if it has not been instantiated explicitly in the Factory class.

Comment: maybe because of annotation, they are getting initialized

Comment: @Tofiq Initialization is understood, but value being set in the children variable feels bit odd to me.